# Using setw when output istringstream to a string, why the length is not right?

Tags: c++, setw

I view an example of `setw` on cppreference. It use `setw` to set the width. In this example it suppose to extract a string to 'arr', and it set width 6. But why 'arr' only have 5 characters, why the result is "hello" not "hello,"? Thank you for your answer.

code source:[std::setw](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw)

```
  #include <sstream>
  #include <iostream>
  #include <iomanip>

  int main()
  {
      std::cout << "no setw:" << 42 << '\n'
                << "setw(6):" << std::setw(6) << 42 << '\n'
                << "setw(6), several elements: " << 89 << std::setw(6) << 12 << 34 << '\n';
      std::istringstream is("hello, world");
      char arr[10];
      is >> std::setw(6) >> arr;
      std::cout << "Input from \"" << is.str() << "\" with setw(6) gave \""
                << arr << "\"\n";
  }
```

Output:

```
  no setw:42
  setw(6):    42
  setw(6), several elements: 89    1234
  Input from "hello, world" with setw(6) gave "hello"
```

Comment: See non-member operator>> for char* argument. As cppreference puts it, it stops when "`st.width()-1` characters are extracted"

Answer (score 0):

`arr` is actually populated with **6** characters, 5 for the *hello* world, the 6th being the terminating NULL character. As you extract into a `char` array, the C++ stream receives only a `char` pointer (arrays decay to pointers in function calls) and assumes that `setw` was used to pass the *size* of the array. So the last position is reserved for the terminating null.

Answer (score 0):

`arr` is not a `std::string` but an array of `char`, thus the explanation of Serge.
Would `arr` be a `std::string`, then it'll contain "hello,".